# Remove anything but alphabets and numeric from string

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I've a text field on UI. It does not restrict user to enter any special char. But while storing it in DB I want anything to be removed except alphabets and numerics.

It can be done at the client (JavaScript) side or the server (Java) side (though I want to do it on server side).

I used

```
str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

to do the task, but it would give an error:

> Invalid char sequence

when entered something like "24 \ 7". Is there any way to handle these kind of escape sequence or I should do it on client side(using javascript)? means remove all unwanted chars in js only?

Comment: `"24 \ 7"` is you string input and you want to convert this into `"24  7"`. Am I correct?

Comment: This sounds like more of an issue of how `str` is created than the replace.  Can you show that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslash literal characters need to occur in pairs otherwise Java will expect a carriage control character (such as `\t` or `\n`)

```
String str = "24 \\ 7";
                  ^
```